# How can I force allocation only in page file?

Tags: c++, windows, memory

When I call VirtualAlloc and pass big size, memory is allocated in page file, but when I try to do so with less size, RAM is used. How can I fix it?

Comment: important remark: it uses RAM when, for example, VirtualAlloc is called by Heap(Re)Alloc. When I do so, page file is used

Comment: You should not, and cannot. The OS moves individual 4KB memory pages between RAM, the page file, and the CPU caches all the time, depending on which pages are currently used, without the programs ever finding out. This is a fundamental part of *virtual* memory. Just because something is first allocated in one part of the memory HW does not mean it will stay there (or that you should care)

Comment: Umm, my task is to use page file in every place it can be used. My current fix of that problem is system-wide memory purging using NtSetSystemInformation and everything is ok. The only question is how to do same thing on alloc?

Comment: Only not currently in use data / code is solely in the page-file.  To be used (run / read / written) it has to be in memory ( and possible the page file ).

Comment: If they're not used they should be released, isn't it? I can freely use memory allocated by VirtualAlloc in page file (kinda slow but i can)

Comment: @blastpolak to use memory in the pagefile it is paged-in to memory first (kernel intercepts the page fault and pages in the required pages) then you can use it.

Comment: I knew that. The one thing i want to know: can I alloc those pagefile-able pages in pagefile? Because now i should send command to immediately purge memory in RAM and kernel moves them to pagefile. This is very useful for me because i don't have very much RAM but have big SSD storage. The only problem I have with external memory purging: it's not fast enough. If some program occupy entire RAM first, my program wouldn't be able to purge it in time and it will lead to massive lags..